# jqGrid Redirect (and not inline / form edit) when click on Edit icon

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

**My jqGrid script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var delete_task_url = "/controller/deleteRecordAction";
var gr = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url:call_url,
        datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20,30],
    colNames:['Task#','Project ID','Task Name', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Created By', 'Created Date', 'Status', 'Action'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'USER_ID',index:'TASK_ID', align:'center',search:false },
        {name:'USER_NAME',index:'TASK_NAME', search:false},
        {name:'ACTION',index:'link', search:false,align:'center',sortable:false, formatter: 'actions',
        formatoptions: {
            keys: true,
            editformbutton: true,
            delOptions: { url: delete_task_url}
        }},
    ],
    pager: "#page",
    shrinkToFit :true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'TASK_ID',
    caption: "Task List",
    gridComplete: function () {
                    var recs = $("#grid").getGridParam("records");
                    $( ".mycontent" ).remove();
                    if (recs == 0 || recs == null) {
                        $('#grid').after("<div class='mycontent' style='color:red;text-align:center'>No Record Found</div>");

                    }

                }
}).navGrid('#page',{ edit:false,add:false,del:true,search:false,cloneToTop:true,refresh:false},
            {

             },{
             //add options


             },{

                        //msg: "do you really want delete this keyword? This delete affect on Eqms filter"

                });
                jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autosearch: true  });
            var topPagerDiv = $('#grid_toppager')[0]; 
            jQuery("#grid_toppager_center", topPagerDiv).remove();

</script>
```

The above script gives me edit and delete icon. The delete operation is working as expected but for edit, I neither want `editformbutton: true` for `form` editing nor `editformbutton: false` for inline editing.

Instead when user clicks on edit icon, it should be redirected to a custom `URL`.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the question interesting and so I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/formatterActionWithRedirectionOnEdit.htm) which demonstrates the corresponding implementation.

Somme comments to the code. First of all one should understand that `formatter: "actions"` set `onclick` attribute on the div with the Edit icon with the value `jQuery.fn.fmatter.rowactions.call(this,'formedit');` or `jQuery.fn.fmatter.rowactions.call(this,'edit');` depend from the value of `editformbutton` property (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L340-L344)). So one have to remove the attribute (the usage of `.prop("onclick", null)` seem the best way corresponds to [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/#entry-longdesc)) and to bind new `click` event handle which assign new URL value to `location.href`. The code from `gridComplete` do that:

```
gridComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this), rows = this.rows, i, iAction, tr,
        colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        idPrefix = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
        newOnClick = function (e) {
            var rowid = $(this).closest(".jqgrow").attr("id");
            e.stopPropagation();

            // an example of redirection
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/#q=" +
                encodeURIComponent($.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix, rowid));
        };

    // find the index of the column with formatter: "actions"
    for (i = 0; i < colModel.length; i++) {
        if (colModel[i].formatter === "actions") {
            iAction = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (iAction === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        tr = rows[i];
        if ($(tr).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
            $(tr.cells[iAction]).find(".ui-inline-edit")
                .click(newOnClick)      // register new click event handler
                .prop("onclick", null); // remove standard behavior of Edit button
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine but a looping only to redirect it to `URL`. Can this be shortened or altered or any other default setting that allows to do so ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. The `click` event handler `newOnClick` provide an example of redirection. `var rowid = $.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix, rowid);` gets the rowid. I appended it to the test URL as an example. You can use `$self.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid)` to get any other data from the row. You can use `$.param` to construct the data which you want append to your URL. So you need just modify the line `window.location.href = ...` corresponds to your requirements.

Comment: Yes, the `URL` modification is done and code is working well. I was just wondering about code length. Thanks again.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: One can reduce the code by usage jQuery selectors to the column with "actions" formatter, but it will work slowly as the code which I posted. In any way I described first what should be done and then posted the implementation.